# Adjust red5's SOSample quality level?

Tags: webcam, red5

Is there any way to adjust the quality level at which RED5's SOSample records a webcam stream? I just installed it on a remote server, and it's recording in an awful quality.

Answer (score 0):

The FLV will be recorded at the level set within your client application, see these specifically (via Adobe):

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/fms/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000548.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality()

Another factor is your bandwidth, if data is dropped or lost in transit to the server it will not be recorded.